# C++ transfer ownership of a struct to a function

Tags: c++, optimization

Is it possible to transfer the ownership of a local variable in C++ (or C++0x) to a function, leaving it undefined after the return, so optimizations can be done?

```c
struct A {
    int a[100000];
};

int func(A& s){
    //s should now be "owned" by func and be undefined in the calling function
    s.a[2] += 4;
    return s.a[2];
}

int main(){
    A s;
    printf("%d\n", func(s));
    //s is now undefined
}
```

I want the function "func" to be optimized to simply return s.a[2]+4, but not change the actual value in memory, just like if "s" had been a local variable in "func".
If it can't be done in standard C++, is it possible with some extension in g++?

Comment: This would be a use case for the `A &&s` "rvalue reference" of C++11 that all of the cool kids are answering questions about, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Henning: Nope, not at all. `A` has no referenced variables that would otherwise require copying, and you can't physically move memory, so an rvalue reference here is meaningless unless you were to perfect forward on it. More than that, `s` is still defined to be valid afterwards, so you can't undefine it in the main function afterwards anyway.

Comment: You say it should "not change the actual value in memory" - but why do you care if memory is changed, if the function 'owns' the struct at that point anyway? I'm not quite sure what you hope to accomplish by this 'optimization'...

Comment: @DreadMG, I would assume that a decent compiler could figure out that the `s` in `main` is dead after the call, such that there is no need to actually copy the memory before you pass it to the function. But perhaps the compiler can already figure this out if the parameter is simply declared as passing an `A` by value.

Comment: @DeadMG: I think Henning may have been suggesting the code be changed to `printf("%d\n", func(A()))`, or similar. That way the A would not be accessible to `main()` after the call to `func`, as the author desires.

Comment: Many optimisations can be done when you operate on a local struct/array compared to a struct/array that have to be valid after the end of the function.

Comment: @Emil: Not when that struct/array is already valid on the scope of another function. Yes, stack allocation is much faster- but allocating on the stack in one function is no better to allocating on the stack in another.

Comment: @Henning: You don't need an rvalue reference to tell the compiler that- and as I said, it doesn't tell the compiler that anyway.

Comment: @jwd: True- but doesn't allow for arbitrary construction of the object.

Comment: @DeadMG - Out of curiosity, why not? Can rvalue references only use parameterless constructors? E.g. is `func(A(x,y,z))` invalid? (Assuming appropriate code added to A's definition)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's not possible, either Standard or through an extension, and that's because there is no optimization value. Compilers can trivially prove that there are no more references to local variables in such situations. Failing all else, you could trivially mimic the effect by doing

```
int main() {
    {
        A s;
        printf("%d\n", func(s));
    }
}
```

Being able to do that kind of thing would be hideously dangerous for no benefit.

Answer (score 2):

Leave optimization to compiler - in simple cases it probably can do it.

Don't forget - premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: If you know what the compiler can't do, but you could have done yourself, there are always room for improvements ;)

Answer (score 1):

I would expect a reasonable optimizing compiler to be able to make an optimization like this without any special hints if the local variable s is really not referenced after the function returns, assuming the variable and the function were in the same compilation unit or you had some form of link time code generation enabled.

You might be able to help the optimizer by scoping your local variable to make it explicit that it can't be accessed beyond the one reference after the function call:

```
int main() {
    {
        A s;
        printf("%d\n", func(s));
    } //s is now undefined
}
```

If you have a specific case that doesn't appear to be optimized as effectively as you think it should then perhaps you can provide more detail about your situation. I'm a little unclear what exactly you mean by the function 'owning' the local variable in this case since you do actually want to access it after the function returns.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing distinct issues like ownership, stack unwinding and value parameters.

> Is it possible to transfer the ownership of a local variable

No. Local variables are local to the scope defined and nobody else can see them or manipulate them in any fashion. You can pass to a function the value of a local variable, a reference to a local variable, or the address of a local variable. When a reference or a pointer to a local variable is passed then the calee can manipulate the *content* of the variable, but by no mean can he influence the scope of the variable in the caller frame. The most common transfer of 'ownership' implies transfer a pointer by value and relying on the callee to take ownership of the *allocated memory*. All forms of variable passing (by value, by ref, by pointer) can handle this, the issue of memory allocation ownership is distinct.

> I want the function "func" to be optimized to simply return s.a[2]+4,
>   but not change the actual value in memory,

Then do exactly that, why make it any more complicated?

```
int func(const A& s){
    return s.a[2] + 4;
}
```

This will do exactly what you describe, but is very unlikely this is what you're actually asking. Making a leap of faith and invoking some psychic powers one would guess that what you're really asking is can an object be at the same time changed in the callee scope and left intact in the caller scope? The answer is obviously no, because memory cannot have different values depending on the caller. You can pass a copy of the object (pass by value) which would allow the caller to manipulate its own copy of the object as it sees fit w/o affecting the original one from the caller scope. OR you can pass const reference, preventing the callee from modifying it, and have the callee copy out whatever it needs to to modify.

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised that nobody else has posted this, but it sounds like what's closest to what you want is simply to remove the reference, and put the function call in a seperate scope

```
int func(A s){ //removed the &
    //s is "owned" by func and changes don't touch anyone else's A objects
    s.a[2] += 4;
    return s.a[2];
}
int main(){
    {
        A s;
        printf("%d\n", func(s));
        // s hasn't changed, func had it's own copy.
    } // s goes out of scope and is deleted
    //s is now undefined
}
```

Comment: That is actually kind of what I want, the problem is that it makes a copy that isn't needed.

Comment: If you want to declare s in an outside scope, pass it to a function, and have the function make changes to it's own version without modifying the one in the outside scope, then the copy IS needed.  (Of course, it could be that you don't need to make changes to a local copy, in which case, see Remus Rusanu's answer)

Comment: Wait, I take it back.  New answer added with auto_ptr

Answer (score 0):

You could also have it pointer based if you prefer that. The code sample below changes your func(A) to take a reference to a pointer so it can be turned safely to null after deallocation.

It's a little bit hooky but it is possible if you absolutely require it. It may be a premature optimization that can be avoided however.

```
int func(A*& s) {
    int retVal = s->a[2] + 4;
    delete s;
    s = NULL;
    return retVal;
}

int main() {
   A* s = new A();
   printf("%d\n", func(s));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the old C++03 auto_ptr for this.  The calling function is left with an auto_ptr that points to nullptr, while the function took over and deleted s.

```
int func(std::auto_ptr<A> s){
    //s is "owned" by func and be undefined in the calling function
    s.a[2] += 4;
    return s.a[2];
}

int main(){
    std::auto_ptr<A> s = new A();
    printf("%d\n", func(s)); //destructive copy of pointer
    //s is now nullptr
}
```